# Batch process RouteFinder tasks in MapInfo

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I am running multiple network analysis processes in MapInfo using RouteFinder. Some of the datasets are large and the processes take a long time, so I would like to be able to set several to run consecutively over the weekend. I am a novice with MapBasic and generally use the viewer window to view code for various tasks and then copy chunks and string them together to produce what I want. However, when Routefinder start the MapBasic window stops displaying.

In this particular case, I want to run the same Nearest process using the same network settings and origin data, so the only thing changing each time would be the destination dataset. I'm guessing there is a simple way to set this up but haven't been able to work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RouteFinder is a tool for MapInfo Pro written using MapBasic and Delphi.

These tools can't be automated using MapBasic and they also don't write out there "MapBasic statements" to the MapBasic window.

The only cance of automating this is if RouteFinder does have a batch feature for the specific process that you are running.

Would one option be to merge your destination dataset and calculate distances between all origin and destinations and then find the nearest?

Comment: Peters last suggestion is also my best idea. Once you have the full distance matrix add a field which tells you which destination set the record belongs to. Could be looked up in the merged destination dataset. Then it is a matter of doing a SQL-group by on the matrix.

Comment: Thanks Peter and Uffe, I will merge all of the destinations and run it all at once. I think this is actually a simpler and better solution than what I thought I wanted to do.